# R script execution of different machines lead to different outcomes

Tags: r, execution

I am new to R and I am working on a script which gets data from a REST API, processes it and saves the outcome locally on the machine. So when I execute the script on my machine it works perfectly fine but when I execute the SAME script on a different machine I get an error("missing where TRUE/FALSE needed" if that helps). 
I know this is kind of a vague description of the problem but I wouldn't know what else to say besides posting the whole source code...
R, RStudio and all the packages are up-to-date. The script doesn't have any parameters.

I am looking for an explaination why the same script works on machine 1 and fails to run on machine 2. 
Am I missing something R-related which might explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: Are both the machine under the same OS? What is the API? What is the function you're running?

Comment: Both Win10 but one is Home and the other is Professional. 
Its a swagger API which is not publicly available. 
I assume you are talking about the programmatical function where the error occurs - it occurs within a while(val1 < val2) statement.

Comment: One of val1 or val2 may be undefined. One reason that might work differently on different machines is if you are using a library that is only installed on one of the machines.  Does your code have some `library` or `require` statements?

Comment: @G5W Yes, it uses library (jsonlite and httr) but I've updated both packages on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the origin of the problem: 
RStudios locale(check with sessionInfo()) differed on both machines. For some reason the unix time was given in microseconds instead of seconds. I noticed that a function argument was "NA". It seems that the numerical value of that argument was too high und resulted in "NA" which ultimatively resulted in errors.

I used Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English") to adjust the settings.